# datanode is starting but no showing in jps

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2

I installed hadoop in ubuntu, when I run the following command:

```
sudo su hduser
cd /usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop 
sudo rm -R /app/* 
sudo rm -R /tmp/* 
hadoop namenode -format 
start-dfs.sh && start-yarn.sh
jps 
~$ jps 
4722 Jps 
4281 ResourceManager 
3971 SecondaryNameNode 
4426 NodeManager 
3603 NameNode
```

*datanode is starting but not showing in jps. I don't know how to fix this issue and when i run the commands `hadoop-daemon.sh stop datanode` or `stop-all.sh`, the datanode is not stopping.

Comment: Update your post with Datanode logs

Comment: is this single or multi node?

Comment: Hi if i have one master node and tree data nodes 1/ where i was stored the data set in order the master node distributed them between the data nodes. ?